# MVC4 Linking Models To SimpleAuthentication Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In the vast amount the tutorials for MVC4, I never see them link the authenticated user to a table containing data that belongs to that user.  I've looked high and low on this and have come up empty.

Take for example a table of Note, each user would store a Note to the database.  How can I take my simple class and link the authenticated user to it?  Below is as close as I feel I've gotten without results.

```
 public class Note
    {
        public int NoteId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Anyone have a good tutorial link or can explain how I should be linking my authenticated user (using simpleauthentication) to models in ASP.net MVC4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your entity to:

```
public class Note
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId{ get; set; }

    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your Note controller or whatever controller you have creating your Notes:

```
    [Authorize]//Place this on each action or controller class so that can can get User's information
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CreateViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var db = new EfDb();                
            try
            {                   
                var userProfile = db.UserProfiles.Local.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name)
                                ?? db.UserProfiles.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
                if (userProfile != null)
                {
                    var note= new Note
                                        {
                                           UserProfile = userProfile,
                                           Description = model.Description 
                                        };                        
                    db.Notes.Add(note);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
                throw;
            }
        }            
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind adding a link to download the project? I am interested to know how you created the EfDB().  And also why do you not have to specify the UserId portion? It looks like when you set the userProfile, it just works.  Is this a pretty common way of approaching this problem?

Comment: Also why do you query the db.UserProfiles.Local ?

Comment: There is no project, i constructed this right here. I assumed you have a EfDatabase class. I used `UserProfile.Local` to avoid unnecessary trip back to the database. Its a way to get `UserId` of the logged in `User` Watch MVC4 videos to learn more from the link. http://pluralsight.com/training/Authors/Details/scott-allen

Comment: @cgatian Oh and i specified `UserId` using `UserProfile = userProfile`. Its an effient practice since we have `userProfile` property in `Note`....Also i would appreciate a vite up if this works out for you.